# Remembering search parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a small website with search filters (textbox and checkboxes). I have searched around and seen that the way to remember the past search filters ONLY AFTER refresh is using session storage.

However, the problem is that, even when the user browses around the website and comes back to the search page, he/she would still see the past search filters. I want to reset the search filters when the user is coming from a different page.

I'm thinking and searching around as to how to remove these variables stored in the session storage after the user leaves the page and only keeping it when the user refreshes.

My current code goes like this :

```
var selectedCompanies = new Array;
var selectedCategories = new Array;
var searchWord = "";

if(sessionStorage.getItem('selectedCompanies') != null){
    selectedCompanies = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('selectedCompanies'));
    alert("NOT NULL!");
    //loop to recheck checkboxes 
}
if(sessionStorage.getItem('selectedCategories') != null){
    selectedCategories = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('selectedCategories'));
    //loop to recheck checkboxes
}
if(sessionStorage.getItem('searchWord') != null){
    searchWord = sessionStorage.getItem('searchWord');
    $('#filter-searchbar').val(searchWord);
}
```

Please help as to how can I delete the variables inside the session storage after the user leaves the search page. Thanks!

Comment: You could use `document.referrer` to check where the user comes from, and not reset the form when he does come from a predefined site

Comment: @RononDex Not a bad idea, but not all browsers/servers set the referrer property.

Comment: Problem with document.referrer is that on REFRESH, the "value" of it is still the last page where the user came from, and not the current page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code in a common JavaScript file. Reference this file on all pages except the search page:

```
sessionStorage.removeItem('selectedCompanies');
sessionStorage.removeItem('selectedCategories');
sessionStorage.removeItem('searchWord');
```

This will clear the search parameters on all other pages but allow the data to persist on the search page.

Comment: @user3286528 No problem. Don't forgot to mark it as the answer if it works for you.